# Float paragraph at bottom of equal height divs

Tags: html, css

Trying to float a paragraph at the bottom of 3 equal height Divs at the bottom of each div. I've got the 3 divs the same height, but unsure how to place the final paragraph at the bottom (it will be a button for each and I want them to line up).

THe 3 divs are all responsive, so the final paragraph needs to be at the bottom regardless of width/height of the div.

[JSfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/qtsdzeyp/2/)

```css
#one-true { overflow: hidden; }
#one-true .col {
  width: 27%;
  padding: 30px 3.15% 0;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: -99999px;
  padding-bottom: 99999px;
}
#one-true .col:nth-child(1) { margin-left: 33.3%; background: #ccc; }
#one-true .col:nth-child(2) { margin-left: -66.3%; background: #eee; }
#one-true .col:nth-child(3) { left: 0; background: #eee; }
p.button {
    text-align:center;}
}
```

```html
<div id="one-true" class="group">
  <div class="col">
      <h3>I am listed first in source order.</h3>
      <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
      <p class="button"><a href="http://jsfiddle.net" target="_blank">Click here</a></p>
    </div>
  <div class="col">
      <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
      <p class="button"><a href="http://jsfiddle.net" target="_blank">Click here</a></p>
    </div>
  <div class="col">
      <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
      <p class="button"><a href="http://jsfiddle.net" target="_blank">Click here</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a completely different approach using flexboxes.

In the example below, the `order` property is used to re-order the elements, `flex-basis: 100%` is used to make the children `.col` elements the same width, and `flex-grow: 1` is used to make the `p` element expand to the remaining height so that the `p.button` element is always placed at the bottom.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/hygv7m5e/)

```css
#one-true {
    display: flex;
}

#one-true .col {
    padding: 30px 3.15% 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-basis: 100%;
}

#one-true .col:nth-child(1) { background: #ccc; order: 2; }
#one-true .col:nth-child(2) { background: #eee; order: 1; }
#one-true .col:nth-child(3) { background: #eee; order: 3; }

#one-true .col p:not(.button) {
    flex-grow: 1;
}

p.button {
    text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div id="one-true" class="group">
    <div class="col">
         <h3>I am listed first in source order.</h3>

        <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
        <p class="button"><a href="http://jsfiddle.net" target="_blank">Click here</a>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
        <p class="button"><a href="http://jsfiddle.net" target="_blank">Click here</a>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
        <p class="button"><a href="http://jsfiddle.net" target="_blank">Click here</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay, what's browser compatibility like with that method? Looks good though.

Comment: @Dan [Support can be found here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox). Currently it is at ~88.88% if you add vendor prefixes for additional browser support.

Answer (score 0):

You can set .col divs to `position:relative` and then each p to `position:absolute; bottom:0` but this would require you make them the same height by an alternative method (nested divs or table-cell), since your current method means the that `bottom:0` puts the paragraph a hundred thousand pixels below view .